# Elasticsearch Kibana plugin not working (Missing app chooser icon)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I installed ELK on Ubuntu, all is working fine. (being able to browse to Kibana from http://sample:5601/app/kibana)

I installed Kibana time-lion plugin following these guidelines:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-timeline

```
mlast@elk:/$ sudo docker run -i -t kibana /bin/bash
root@2816533dd8a5:/# cd bin
root@2816533dd8a5:/bin# kibana plugin -i kibana/timelion
Installing timelion
Attempting to extract from https://download.elastic.co/kibana/timelion/timelion-latest.tar.gz
Downloading 3381940 bytes....................
Extraction complete
Optimizing and caching browser bundles...
Plugin installation complete
```

After installation I was expecting to see the [Kibana app chooser](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/docs/apps.asciidoc) icon but it does not exist. moreover when trying to browse to this url http://sample:5601/app/timelion I am getting

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Unknown app timelion"}
```

What seems to be the issue? I also trying to install other Kibana plugin such as [Marvel](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html) but still, I am not being able to see the icon

Answer (score 0):

You need restart kibana for load the new plugins.

Additional you are using docker, add persistence in plugins

```
sudo docker run -i -t -v /to/path/host/plugins:/opt/kibana/installedPlugins kibana
```

Comment: it is an kibana plugin so he needs to restart kibana